# Blazor Client: Circuit has been shut down due to error

Tags: c#, blazor-client-side

I have just started out with Blazor and it appears it still isn't in a stable condition. Upon navigating to another page, with the force load argument set to true I receive an error.

Upon navigating, a JS console error appears (before page left):

```
[2020-11-01T00:10:47.009Z] Error: Circuit has been shut down due to error.
```

The code:

```
NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/", true);
```

If `false` is passed to `NavigateTo` method, this error does not happen. The issue is that I am on the same page (`/`) when navigating, so esentially I need to reload the page forcefully.

`location.reload();` produces the same issue.

Comment: take look at https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/25907